# Select only certain colors for a product in Magento

Tags: magento, colors, attributes, selection

I just downloaded Magento and was playing with the product attributes. Is there a way to make a product only show specific colors that are available in inventory. Say Shirt one only comes in red, white and blue.

Is there a way to only show these colors to be available in the shopping cart? Or do I have to create unique color attributes for each item?

I know the color list is quite extensive and I can see adding a couple colors, but not all will be needed for each product.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a configurable product.

To do this you need to create an attribute "color" that can be used for configurable type products.

Once it is created you can use this attribute to define your product details including color. For more details see [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product) link.

Comment: if only the available colors should be displayed in the frontend, after creating the configurable product, you need to change the config setting in `System > Configuration > CATALOG > Inventory > Stock Options >  Display Out of Stock Products` to No